# Executable requirements, PHPUnit and Jenkins strategy

Tags: jenkins, phpunit, tdd

We use Jenkins and PHPUnit in our development. For long time I wanted to start to use executable requirements in our team. Architect/team leader/someone who defines requirements can write tests before actual code. Actual code then should be written by another team member. Therefore executable requirements tests are committed to repository before actual code is made, Jenkins rebuilds the project and rightfully fails. And project remains in failed state until new code is written which defeats XP rule to keep project in good state at all times.

Is there any way to tell PHPUnit that such and such tests should not be run under Jenkins while they may be executed locally by any dev with ease? Tweaking phpunit.xml is not really desirable: local changes to tests are better as they easier to keep track of.

We tried markTestIncomplete() and markTestSkipped() but they not really do what we need: executable requirements tests are really complete and should not be skipped. Use of these functions prevent easy execution of such tests in development.

The best approach in our case would be to have PHPUnit option like --do-not-run-requirements which should be used by PHPUnit executed by Jenkins. On dev machine this option should not be used and actual executable requirements tests should have @executableRequirements meta-comment in the beginning (removed only after actual code is created and tested). Issue that PHPUnit does not have such functionality.

May be there is a better way to achieve implementation of executable requirements without "false" failures in Jenkins?

Answer (score 1):

With PHPUnit, tests can be filtered for execution. Either annotate tests that should not be executed in one environment using the `@group` annotation and then use `--exclude-group <name-of-group>` or the `<group>` element of PHPUnit's XML configuration file or the `--filter <pattern>` commandline option. Both approaches are covered in the documentation.

Comment: With the groups what would take precedence: command line or XML config? I guess CLI should override whatever is in XML config but for sake of community it would be nice to have the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

> For long time I wanted to start to use Test Driven Development in our
> team. I don't see any problem with writing tests before actual code.

This is *not* TDD.

To quote from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development):

> first the developer writes an (initially failing) automated test case
> that defines a desired improvement or new function, then produces the
> minimum amount of code to pass that test, ...

Notice the `test case` in the singular.

Having said that, you are quite welcome to define your own development methodology whereby one developer write *tests* in the plural, commits them to version control and another developer writes code to satisfy the tests.

The solution to your dilemma is to commit the tests to a branch and the other developer work in that branch. Once all the tests are passing, merge with trunk and Jenkins will see the whole lot and give its opinion on whether the tests pass or not.

Just don't call it TDD.

Comment: "Test case" on its own does not specify number of assertions to be made or does not define "complexity of the case". Therefore "test case" as such may be whole *Test.php in PHPUnit. But that's not my point: whatever we call it you are right - it is development methodology I am interested in. Repository branching may be GOOD solution in general but we opted for multiple smaller repositories and no branches instead of one large repository with branches. Another good answer would be to write "minimum amount of code to pass that test" and let devs to modify it then.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine it would not be very straight forward in practice to write tests without any basic framework. Hence, 'minimum amount of code to pass the test' approach as you suggested is not a bad idea.

**Not necessarily a TDD approach**
-Who writes the tests? If someone who works with requirements or an QA member writes the tests, you could probably simply write empty tests (so they don't fail). This approach will make sure that the developer will cover all the cases that the other person has thought about. An example test method would be `public void testThatObjectUnderTestReturnsXWhenACondition, public void testThatObjectUnderTestReturnsZWhenBCondition`. (I like long descriptive names so there are no confusions as to what I am thinking or you can use comments to describe your tests). The DEVs can write code and finish the tests or let someone else finish the tests later. Another way of stating this is to write executable requirements. See Cucumber/Steak/JBehave as executable requirements tools.

Having said above, we need to differentiate whether you are trying to write executable requirements or unit/integration/acceptance tests.

If you want to write executable requirements, any one can write it and could be empty to stop them from failing. DEVs will then fill it up and make sure the requirements are covered. My opinion is to let the DEVs deal with unit /integration/acceptance tests using TDD (actual TDD) and not separate the responsibility of writing code and appropriate unit/integration/acceptance tests for the code they write.

Comment: Thank your for bringing clear distinction between "executable requirements" and TDD. I will amend my original question accordingly. But why it would be empty to stop them from failing? Of course executable requirements WILL fail originally - we know that. There no need to show FAIL on build in Jenkins. It is enough to see it on dev machine. After dev has completed coding of new feature then he allows these requirements to be executed by Jenkins as well: this way devs would be aware of requirements from onset, Jenkins would not show false failures, will show failures after coding is done.

Comment: They don't have to fail assuming the intention is to communicate the requirements. Empty tests shouldn't fail because they are simply empty methods. If not, set the tests up so they don't fail.